# Calendar event organisers receive no confirmation of accept or decline

Tags: high-sierra, calendar, ical

I'm on High Sierra, using iPhone and MacBook Pro.
I receive invites in my Apple Calendar app from Outlook users without problems. I get the Accept, Maybe and Decline buttons as expected. When I accept an invite it appears on all my devices without problem, but the sender of the invite doesn't receive confirmation that I have accepted or declined the invite.

I have checked that my contact card has the right email address, not sure what else to do.

Any thoughts or advice?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  These can be tricky. Do you know the hosting provider you use to send the response and the hosting provider that the sender uses? Exchange might not be detailed enough, you might need to know O365 or on prem and specifics if they can’t help you trace the invite and response.